# UWP Convert IEnumerable to ObservableCollection (x:Bind)

Tags: c#, listview, uwp, observablecollection, xbind

Okay, so I have a `IEnumerable` collection which I `x:Bind` into a `ListView`.

While the app is running I want whenever this `IEnumerable` list changes, my `listview` to be updated as well. This is not the case even when using `INotifyPropertyChanged`, so I decided to move towards converting the `IEnumerable` to an `ObservableCollection`.

I found out that the cast that exists is:

```
myCollection = new ObservableCollection<object>(the_list);
```

That would work fine in a different problem, but in my case I am x:Bind this to the `listview` and each time I run the method with the above code a new reference is created and the bind will not work (It doesn't work). Is that correct ? If yes how can I work around this ? If not, what am I doing wrong ? Thank you.

Currently my code looks like:

```
public ObservableCollection<IMessage> MessageList;

private async Task SetMessages()
{
    MessageList = new ObservableCollection<IMessage>(await channel.GetMessagesAsync(NumOfMessages).Flatten());
}
```

**What Worked for me:**

Thanks solely to the Marian Dolinský's answer everything works now. I present some for of my code to make it more clear What I've done was:

```
class ChatViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    //Number of messages to have in list at once.
    private int NumOfMessages = 20;

    //Called when a user clicks on a channel.
    public async Task SelectChannel(object sender, ItemClickEventArgs e)
    {
        //Set the channel to clicked item
        channel = (SocketTextChannel)e.ClickedItem;
        //Receive the messages in the list.
        IEnumerable<IMessage> data = await channel.GetMessagesAsync(NumOfMessages).Flatten();
        //Clear the observablecollection from any possible previous messages (if for example you select another channel).
        messageList.Clear();
        //Loop and add all messages to the observablecollection
        foreach (var item in data)
        {
            messageList.Add(item);
        }
    }

    //The event handler when a message is received.
    private async Task Message_Received(SocketMessage arg)
    {
        //Calls to add message only if the message received is of interest.
        if (arg.Channel == channel)
        {
            //Sets the thread equal to the UI thread.
            await Windows.ApplicationModel.Core.CoreApplication.MainView.CoreWindow.Dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, () =>
             {
                //Adds the new message, removes the oldest to keep always 20.
                 messageList.Add(arg);
                 messageList.Remove(messageList[0]);
             });
        }
    }

    private ObservableCollection<IMessage> messageList = new ObservableCollection<IMessage>();

    public ObservableCollection<IMessage> MessageList
    {
        get
        {
            return messageList;
        }
    }
}
```

And here is the code in XAML:

```
<Page.DataContext>
    <vm:ChatViewModel x:Name="ChatViewModel"/>
</Page.DataContext>

                    <ListView VerticalContentAlignment="Bottom" ItemsSource="{x:Bind ChatViewModel.MessageList, Mode=OneWay}" SelectionMode="None" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource MessageListDataTemplate}">
                        <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
                            <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
                                <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
                                <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0,0,5,5"/>
                            </Style>
                        </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
                    </ListView>
```

Thanks again for your help :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not updated because of how the `ObservableCollection` works - it notifies only about changes inside the collection but when you are assigning the `MessageList` in your `SetMessages` method, you're creating new instance of `ObservableCollection` and the `ListView.Source` is pointing to the original bound instance of `ObservableCollection`.

Also, I see that `MessageList` is not a property, but field. Fields doesn't work with bindings.

You have four options how to achieve updating of the `ListView`:

1) You could synchronize the existing `MessageList` with new data:

```
private async Task SetMessages()
{
    IEnumerable newData = await channel.GetMessagesAsync(20).Flatten();

    // Assuming MessageList is not null here you will sync newData with MessageList
}
```

2) If you are not using the `MessageList` collection anywhere else, you can set the `ItemsSource` property of `ListView` directly from code:

```
private async Task SetMessages()
{
     YourListView.ItemsSource = await channel.GetMessagesAsync(20).Flatten();
}
```

3) Since you are using the `x:Bind` expression, you can call `Bindings.Update();` method everytime you want to refresh any binding on the page:

```
private async Task SetMessages()
{
    MessageList = new ObservableCollection<IMessage>(await channel.GetMessagesAsync(20).Flatten());
    Bindings.Update();
}
```

4) You could implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` on the page or create `DependencyProperty` for the `MessageList` and then bind it with `Mode` set to `OneWay`:

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{x:Bind MessageList, Mode=OneWay}">
```

Personally I'd not recommend the fourth option. The best option would be to sync the data since `ListView` automatically animates adding and removing the ListViewItems.

**EDIT:**

I think the problem is in these two lines:

```
messageList.Add(arg);
messageList.Remove(messageList[NumOfMessages - 1]);
```

since new items are added at the end of the collection, so you are removing the item you added last time. For deleting the oldest item, you should use `messageList.RemoveAt(0);` to remove the item at the first position.

Comment: Define "sync" the data. Like copy each item from one to the other ?

Comment: Yeah, iterating through `MessageList` and comparing the items with items you've got in `newData`. For example adding the item to `MessageList` if it's not there already, removing the item from `MessageList` if it doesn't exist in the `newData`, or updating the item if it's in both collections but has been changed.

Comment: Okay lets agree that my data are synced. I have also made a property as well and bind that property. Initially when the app starts, the listview gets the data but even if an item gets added it doesn't update. This is my `ItemsSource="{x:Bind ChatViewModel.MessageList, Mode=OneWay}"` in my listview.

Comment: If it's not updated, it seems like you are creating new instance of `MessageList` after it was bound or it is null when it is bound. Personally I'd make it [this way](https://pastebin.com/Vf8pQ7hv) and even the first data will be added using "syncing".

Comment: Please also note - for the synchronization.. If you are comparing custom class that does not override `Equals` method, `==` and `!=` operators then using the `==` or `!=` operator is comparing reference equality.

Comment: On the code you gave me you say it can only be modified in the constructor but you modify it and create a new instance. Thanks for the tip on syncing. I edited my question with the current situation.

Comment: Yes, I modify it and create a new instance but in the constructor of the `ChatViewModel` class. Take a look at [it](https://pastebin.com/Vf8pQ7hv) again, I've updated the code a bit. And please add more context to the code, like class where the `MessageList` property is and the XAML because I don't see any reason why it should not work.

Comment: I have edited my questions once more including the class name and the XAML code. I understood what you said about the constructor. I have implemented it and it does the same thing. App opens normally but when new message comes it just doesn't update the bind.

Comment: First of all, I see that the `ChatViewModel` class inherits from the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface, but does not implements the `PropertyChangedEvent` but I think you just omitted it in the code here.

Comment: That was a good point. I know this is talking too long but I am trying to figure this out! I updated a bit my code based on your comment with some more info.

Comment: How do I see that ? :/ I have implemented that:
https://www.thomaslevesque.com/2009/04/17/wpf-binding-to-an-asynchronous-collection/
And it still doesn't work! (Crashes after adding)

Comment: So you created a custom collection class? And what does the exception say when the app crashes?

Comment: It doesn't crash because it happens inside an event handler and the handler probably has a try catch thing inside (I think). I have updated my question with interesting observations.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/138372/discussion-between-marian-dolinsky-and-konkarapas).